# How can you use a (fair) coin to draw straws among 3 people? (Information Theory)

Tags: information-theory

The following nice riddle is a quote from the excellent, free-to-download book: [Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/itila/book.html), written by [David J.C. MacKay](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/).

> How can you use a (fair) coin to draw straws among 3 people?

Comment: Toss it twice, retry on one of the 4 possible outcomes.

Comment: I read in a book once (don't remember which) about how to accomplish lovely probabilities like $1/\pi$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n$ be probabilities adding up to $1$. Each $p_k$ represents the desired probability for the $k$th straw to be drawn.

Let

- $q_0 = 0$
- $q_1 = p_1$
- $q_2 = p_1 + p_2$
- $q_3 = p_1 + p_2 + p_3$
- $\cdots$
- $q_n = 1$

Consider the intervals $I_1 = (0, q_1), I_2=(q_1, q_2), \ldots, I_n=(q_{n-1},q_n)$ of the real line. We are going to produce a uniformly random real number between $0$ and $1$ and see which interval it lies in. The probability that it lies in the $k$th interval will then be $p_k$.

We will construct our number by flipping a coin repeatedly to form the bits of a binary fraction. In practice, we will stop as soon as we can determine which interval it lies in, but for simplicity we will deal with the entire sequence at once.

Let $r_1,r_2,\ldots$ be the results of the coin flips, where 1 represents heads and 0 represents tails.

Let $r = 0.r_1r_2\ldots$, interpreted as a binary fraction.

We will assume without proof that this procedure produces a uniform random distribution.

We will consider the bits of $r$ one at a time (as the coin is flipped).

Looking at the first $j$ bits of $r$ will allow us to see that $r$ lies in a certain interval $K_j$ of length $2^{-j}$: each additional bit halves the length of the interval. For example, if the first bit is $1$, then we know that $r \in [0.1,1]$. If the first bit is $1$ and the second is $0$, then we know that $r \in [0.1,0.11]$.

Note that once $2^{-j} < \min \bigl\{p_k: 1 \le k \le n\bigr\}$, or, equivalently, $j > \log_2 \bigl(1 \big/ \min \{p_k: 1 \le k \le n\}\bigr)$, $K_j$ will intersect at most two intervals $I_m, I_{m+1}$.

At this point, the only remaining question is whether $r < q_m$, $r > q_m$, or $r = q_m$. Since the case of $r = q_m$ has probability $0$, we will assume that it does not occur.

Then by the time $2^{-j} < \big|r - q_m\big|$, $K_j$ will lie entirely to the left or entirely to the right of $q_m$, and $r$ will have been determined to lie in $I_m$ or $I_{m+1}$.

The closer $r$ is to $q_m$, the longer the procedure will take, but as long as they are not actually equal, it will eventually terminate.

A somewhat more practical description:

Represent $q_0, q_1 \ldots, q_n$ in binary:

$q_0 = 0.000\ldots$, $q_1 = 0.b_{11}b_{12}\ldots, q_2 = 0.b_{21}b_{22}\ldots$.

Flip a fair coin. If the coin comes up $0$, then our number is in the interval $(0, 0.1)$, so we discard from consideration any interval whose left endpoint has a first bit of $1$. That is, if $b_{k-1,1} = 1$, then we discard $I_k$. If the first coin comes up $1$, we discard from consideration any interval whose right endpoint has a first bit of $0$. That is, if $b_{k,1} = 0$, we discard $I_k$.

Flip the coin again, this time focusing on the second bit of each endpoint.

Keep flipping until only one interval is left.

Note: there is probably a more efficient/effective to describe this procedure, but I don't remember where I read of it.

Comment: @Dror: I don’t think that you’ve understood the method: your last two comments don’t really make much sense.

Comment: @Dror: I can’t elaborate: I literally have no idea what you’re thinking or trying to say, because what you’ve said seems to have almost no connection with the method that dfeuer describes.

Comment: @Dror: Since your comment about not distinguishing probabilities such as $1/2$ from ‘infinitesimal probabilities’ is nonsense, I think that another explanation is rather more likely: you don’t understand the method.

Comment: Note that this method, while it is certainly a really cool way to do this, has the same basic "problem" that the simpler version above does. Namely, it provides an algorithm that is not guaranteed to terminate (one might get the sequence corresponding to $\frac{1}{3}$ in which case, it will never be possible to determine if it is the first or second person that wins). I did not calculate the expected number of coin tosses for this method, but it is $\frac{8}{3}$ for the other one and I think it is probably close to the same for this method).

Comment: Can you figure out which numbers of straws can be simulated with a halting guarantee? It looks like my approach requires an expected $3$ flips. I'm thinking the approach in the first answer is probably the most efficient one possible. I wonder how that could be proved, and how to calculate the most efficient algorithm for any given assignment of probabilities to $n$ straws.

Comment: The probabilities that can be found with a certainty of halting are precise the powers of $2$ (if you have a maximal number of tosses, then you may as well assume that you always do all the tosses, and you have some power of $2$ outcomes, each with the same probability, so to partition these into equal sized pieces, those pieces must also each have size a power of $2$).

Comment: This method may not halt in all cases, but it halts with probability 1, which is the best that you can hope for.

Answer (score 10):

To expand on Tobias' comment, designate that Player 1 wins on TT (Tails followed by Tails), Player 2 wins on TH, and Player 3 wins on HT. On HH, simply discard the result and flip again. Since all outcomes are equally likely and each player has a single winning outcome, the winner will be chosen uniformly at random.

Comment: And what do you do if you keep getting $H$s?

Comment: Although that is possible, the probability that it will happen is $0$, so unless your name is Rosencrantz, or Guildenstern, you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Though, @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez is absolutely right - This is not a real solution.

Comment: It is a real solution. It's not guaranteed to halt, but it does guarantee a probability of exactly $1/3$ for each outcome.

Comment: @dfeuer, then «keep flipping the coin and never decide anything» is also a solution :-)

Comment: No it's not, because "keep flipping the coin and never decide anything" gives probability $0$ to each of the three results. The procedure suggested in this answer leads to the right probabilities.

Comment: If you keep getting $H$ you record it and upload it on youtube.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: the question specifies a __fair__ coin.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon, I don't know in what way my algorithm conflicts with that.

Comment: @dfeuer, then «if the two flips give $HH$, player $1$ wins, if $HT$, player 2 winds, if $TH$, player 3 wins, and if $TT$ then keep flipping and never decide» :-)

Comment: Of course, I am being facetious... Austin's proposal has the property —that none of mine do— that it gives an answer with probability almost certainly. This should probably have been part of the specification of the problem

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez , Actually , the specification of the problem SCREAMS out (implicitly) that the solutions should have nothing to do with a probability. It is certain. How on earth can straw drawing fail? ....Iiiiin anticipation of humorous sugestions of circumstances in which it fails!... :D

Comment: @Dror, I have a friend who was drawing straws and a meteor fell on him! He did not even know what happened to him, poor soul.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: I was responding to your first comment.  Alas, the SE comment model doesn't allow for such subtleties.